# IRC Hostmask matching

Tags: php, regex, irc

For my IRC bot I need to match a hostmask with another hostmask with wildcards in it.

Example:

Pablo!Pablo@Pablo.users should match: Pa?lo!P?blo@??blo.users

The questionmark means every character and number.

If it's possible then it would be nice to see it match the string below:

Pablo!Pablo@Pablo.users matches with Pablo!Pablo@Pab*

The ! and @ are always in the hostmask.

Could someone make a regular expression for this task?

I've tried, succeeded but the code is huge and often inaccurate.

Thanks allot!

Comment: When you say 'huge' - what, 100 lines? 5,000? If it's 100 lines or less, I'd say post it in your question along with test cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this for my PHPIRCd I'm creating.

```
function match($mask, $expression) {
    $expression = str_replace('\\*', '.+', preg_quote($expression, '/'));
    return preg_match('/^' . $expression. '$/', $mask);
}
```

You could call it like so: `match('Pablo!Pablo@Pablo', 'Pab*o!*@*blo')`. This may not be exactly what you're looking for, but I hope it sends you on the right track.

Comment: If you need a Perl solution, you can use `matches_mask()` from the the [`IRC::Utils`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IRC::Utils#matches_mask) module.